# Using globalProperties in Vue 3 and Typescript

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vetur

I've added a global property in main.ts, and am trying to access this in a component. however I'm getting the error:

```
Property '$const' does not exist on type 'ComponentPublicInstance<{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, EmitsOptions, {}, {}, false, ComponentOptionsBase<{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, EmitsOptions, string, {}>>'.Vetur(2339)
```

I think I need to augment the type, typescript considers $const to be any type right now, however I don't know how to do this in Vue 3 and there is no mention in the docs.

main.ts

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import store from "./store";
import * as constants from "@constants";

const app = createApp(App);

app.config.globalProperties.$const = Object.freeze(constants);

app.use(store);

app.mount("#app");
```

component

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Header",

  computed: {
    tags() {
      return Object.entries(this.$const.TAGS);
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can augment the `@vue/runtime-core` TypeScript module in your application:

```
declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $const: Record<string, unknown>;
  }
}

export {}  // Important! See note.
```

Here is a documentation: [ComponentCustomProperties](https://vuejs.org/api/utility-types.html#componentcustomproperties)

**Important note:** TS module augmentation works correctly **only** when it is placed in a [module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html).

> In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a
> top-level `import` or `export` is considered a module. Conversely, a
> file without any top-level `import` or `export` declarations is treated as a script whose contents are available in the global scope (and therefore to modules as well).

Therefore the file must contain at least one top-level `import` or `export` statement, even if empty one (as in the example above) - [Type Augmentation Placement](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/options-api.html#type-augmentation-placement)

Comment: Why `'@vue/runtime-core'` and not 'vue' as stated in the docs?

Comment: You should be augmenting `vue` instead, _but_ there's [webstorm bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-59818/Vue-custom-global-properties-added-by-augmenting-vue-are-not-resolved) (maybe same thing in vetur?), and so it's nicer to augment one or both of runtime-core and regular vue

Comment: I had to augment `'@vue/runtime-core'` when using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Adding the `export {}` breaks my other ```declare module '*.vue' {
  import { DefineComponent } from 'vue';
  const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>;
  export default component;
}```