# How to access `app.config.globalProperties` in a`<script setup lang="ts">`?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, event-bus, vue-script-setup

how to access `app.config.globalProperties`  withing `<script setup lang="ts">` ?

I have looked around for several approaches: [like this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64175742/using-globalproperties-in-vue-3-and-typescript/64189046#64189046), and tried to combine elements below:

```js
\\ main.ts

import mitt from 'mitt'
const emitter = mitt()

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  export interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    emitter: typeof mitt
  }
}

app.config.globalProperties.emitter = emitter
```

tried packaging for use in composition-api .. no luck either

```js
\\ bus.ts

import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'

const app = getCurrentInstance()
const bus = app.appContext.config.globalProperties.emitter // app is undefined

export const useBus = () => ({ bus })
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You can use [getCurrentInstance](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#getcurrentinstance) only in `setup` or lifecycle hooks of a Vue component
2. Properties added to `app.config.globalProperties` are exposed directly on component instances

So my preferred solution would be:

```js
// bus.ts 

import mitt from 'mitt'

export const emitter = mitt()
export const useBus = () => ({ bus: emitter })
```

```js
// main.ts

import { emitter } from `bus.ts`

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  export interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    emitter: typeof emitter
  }
}

app.config.globalProperties.emitter = emitter
```

Now you can use `this.emitter` in Options API or in templates. And `const { bus } = useBus()` in `setup`

Although I would probably use just single name (either `emitter` or `bus`) :)